# How to have multiple versions of the same object, each with different properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, object, properties

I'm making a text based version of Skyrim and I'm unable to find a way to make enchantments/smithing bonuses work. I have a class for weapons and a class for armor. I have an object for each weapon and piece of armor included in my game. My properties for weapons are name, basedamage, smithingbonus, enchantment, and value. For armor the properties are name, slot, basedefense, smithingbonus, enchantment, and value.

You are able to have multiple of the same item in your inventory which creates the problem of being unable to have different versions of the same item. For example, let's say you have 2 iron swords and you want to enchant one. If you do this using ironsword.enchantment = [firedamage, 20], now both iron swords and every iron sword you find from now on will have a 20 fire damage enchantment. The same issue occurs with smithing where if you enhance one iron sword, all iron swords will become enhanced.

Does anyone know a solution to this? One I can think of would be to have like 1000 versions of each object and that each time you get a new one you would get the next object. For example: the first iron sword you got would be the object ironsword1. The next time you get an ironsword it would be ironsword2 and this would continue until you got 1000 iron swords. This would obviously be very time consuming to implement and I feel like there is definitely a better way.

Comment: Please show some code as to how you’re doing this? I’d assume just have a list of items in inventory and they are all instances of those classes and then enchanting one will not affect the others and so on.

Comment: Sounds like your class hierarchy isn't set up correctly, but with no sample code in your question, it's impossible to know. Suggest you [edit] your question and fix this omission.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding how classes work, or more specifically the difference between classes and instances.

It makes sense to have a class for `Weapon`, but you don't want `IronSword` to be an instance of that class, you'll want it to be a subclass. In your inventory you'd then have two instances of the class `IronSword` with specific enchantments. Alternatively, you might not do an explicit subclass for iron swords but simply instantiate multiple weapons with parameters that identify them as iron swords. But either way, one `object` should correspond to one object, i.e. each inventory option should be a separate object.

Here is a very good series of YouTube videos that give an introduction to OOP in Python:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM

Comment: If I used a subclass for every type of weapon and armor in the game wouldn't I still need to have ~1000 objects for each subclass? Another solution I thought of would be to have 3-4 different "levels" for each enchantment and 3-4 levels for each smithing buff so that way I could have ironswordfiredamage1smithing0, ironswordfiredamage2smithing0 etc althought this would also take forever to implement as there are 8 weapon enchantments and 19 armor enchantments.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You don't want to pre-create all the objects you will ever need, you create them as you need them. The enchantments you would probably want to implement as attributes of the class.
So say you find two iron swords, then you create two objects of that class and place them in your inventory. When you decide to apply the enchantment to one of them, you apply this enchantment to one of the two instances in your inventory.
Note: I think your class structure will get quite complicated, so think carefully about how you want to implement it and make a sketch.

Comment: But do have a look at the tutorial, I think it will help.

Comment: My only problem with this is I can't figure out how to name the objects as I create them. You don't get the iron swords in a set order and you can get an unlimited amount of them if you want. how do i name the objects ironsword0 the first time you get one and ironsword1 the second time and so on?

Comment: You don't need to name them at all. Your inventory could be a list and when you get a new one you just do sth like `inventory.append(IronSword())`

Comment: Would this work if iron sword were still an object like I have it right now or does it have to be a subclass?

Comment: "iron sword" should definitely never be an object. **a specific** iron sword would be an object. Whether it's an object of type `Weapon`, `Sword`, or `IronSword` you'll have to figure out when you design your class architecture.

Answer (score 0):

When you crate two instance or an object they are not the same thing. Let's sat I have a generic class Triangle with attributes a, b, c. I can have two different triangle with different side length at the same time. You have to modify the attribute of only 1 instance of armor/weapon at a time. Can you post an example of your class weapon/object implementation so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Edit:

Let's try to explain class and subclass with your environment. We want do define a generic object called weapon, that has some attribute for damage and range.

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, dmg):
        self.dmg = dmg
        self.range = 1
        self.ench = None
        self.upg = None
    def enchant(self, value):
        self.ench = value
    def upgrade(self, value):
        self.upg = value
    def __str__(self):
        return "Generic weapon, {} dmg and {} range".format(self.dmg, self.range)
```

Now we want to create a subclass named Sword, that inherit everything from the generic class, but can implement more specific attribute and function.

```
class Sword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, dmg):
        Weapon(self, dmg)
        self.range = 5
    def __str__(self):
        "Sword, {} dmg, {} range, {} enchant, {} upgrade"
           .format(self.dmg, self.range, self.ench, self.upg)
```

You can now use both type of weapon in the same style, subclass ING the generic parent class.

```
a = Weapon(2)
b = Sword(5)
c = Sword(5)
c.enchant(2)
d = Sword(5)
d.upgrade(1)
print("{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(a,b,c,d))

=> Generic weapon, 2 dmg and 1 range
   Sword, 5 dmg, 5 range, None enchant, None upgrade
   Sword, 5 dmg, 5 range, 2 enchant, None upgrade
   Sword, 5 dmg, 5 range, None enchant, 1 upgrade
```

I hope you get some of this concept, I suggest you look more into this from some tutorial online, you can just search for OOP.

Comment: The issue is that there is only one object per item but this item appears multiple times  throughout the game so if I wanted to enchant my iron sword, every iron sword I found, bought or ones that enemies use would also have this enchantment.